# AppSync JS resolver: DynamoDB update function does not accept condition object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I try to use `import { update } from "@aws-appsync/utils/dynamodb";` to create a `DynamoDBUpdateItemRequest`. It works well with specifying key and update values, but when I add a condition, the following error is raised:

`Property 'condition' is invalid condition object`

This is what I try to do:

```
import { update } from "@aws-appsync/utils/dynamodb";

export function request(ctx) {
  const updateObj = {
    key: { id: ctx.identity.username },
    update: {
      name: ctx.arguments.newProfile.name,
      imageUrl: ctx.arguments.newProfile.imageUrl,
    },
    // When active, this line leads to the error:
    condition: { expression: "attribute_exists(id)" },
  };

  const requestObj = update(updateObj);

  // Workaround: Attach the condition object to the generated DynamoDBUpdateItem
  // requestObj.condition = { expression: "attribute_exists(id)" };
  return requestObj;
}

export function response(ctx) {
  return ctx.result;
}
```

Is this a bug, or does the condition object really have the wrong format?